# Azure Web App File Download - Problem with special characters

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, azure-web-app-service

i have a problem downloading files with special characters...

My web site (mvc.net framework) can upload files with the name "dummy _ + [] @@ # @@] [@] 3.pdf", i can see it physically on my FTP server but when i try to download with url "https://fakeurl.con/Attachments/dummy _ + [] @@ # @@] [@] 3.pdf" i have a 404 (The resource cannot be found.).

I tried adding in web.config file:

- requestPathInvalidCharacters=""
- system.webServer -> security --> requestFiltering -> allowDoubleEscaping="true"
- system.webServer -> security --> requestFiltering -> allowHighBitCharacters="true"

But nothing has changed...

Someone can help me?
Thanks

Valerio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `allowDoubleEscaping` setting actually works, however there are some reasons causing the file could not be open.

Firstly I try without `allowHighBitCharacters` setting and set the `allowDoubleEscaping`, eventually only the `#` could not be recognized, so I change it to `%23` and the it will work.

[image]

Secondly I add the `allowHighBitCharacters` and then all special character won't work.

So just only use the `allowDoubleEscaping` and if don't mind convert `#` to `%23`.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was the # and i don't want to allow it so... that's perfect!
Have a nice day!